# web filter cannot read Property file in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have simple ip filter, which will filter ips not in white list. 
The code is simple, like

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class ClientIpFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties appProperties;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        HashSet<String> trustedIps = loadAccessIPList();
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Enumeration<String> headers = req.getHeaderNames();
        while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
            String str = (String) headers.nextElement();
            headerMap.put(str, req.getHeader(str));
        }
.............

}
```

And I define a Configuration to include it.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            ClientIpFilter securityFilter = new ClientIpFilter();
            registrationBean.setFilter(securityFilter);
            registrationBean.setOrder(1);
            return registrationBean;
        }   
}
```

But the Filter cannot autowired AppProperties which includes configuration from my application.preperties.

Comment: AppProperties? Is it your custom class? If, then you need not create separate class to read value from properties. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Well of course it cannot because it isn't a `@Bean`. Thus no spring bean, no injection... You are creating a new instance yourself, move that logic to a separate `@Bean` method and make the `ClientIPFilter` a bean.

Comment: Yes, the AppProperty is a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Your AppProperties file should be like below with annotations and appropriate prefix as mentioned in application.properties file

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.test")

public class AppProperties {

private String name;

private String age;


}
```

The @EnableConfigurationProperties should not be required in ClientFilter class. Just autowiring the Properties file should be ok ..

Comment: I have tried this before. It works in normal spring bean. But in a filter, it doesn't work. The AppProperties always throws null point.

Answer (score 0):

I find the root reason. I need to let the ClientIpFilter to be a component so that it can be autowired, then spring can register other property.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class ClientIpFilter implements Filter {
@Autowired
private AppProperties appProperties;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    HashSet<String> trustedIps = loadAccessIPList();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

.............

}